# I can't get the tiny grad README example to work

Tags: deep-learning

I tried out the GitHub project, tinygrad, and it shows a Torch example, and an equivalent TinyGrad example.

For

```
import torch

x = torch.eye(3, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([[2.0,0,-2.0]], requires_grad=True)
z = y.matmul(x).sum()
z.backward()

print(x.grad)  # dz/dx
print(y.grad)  # dz/dy
```

I get a sensible looking

```
tensor([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [-2., -2., -2.]])
tensor([[1., 1., 1.]])
```

but when I try

```
from tinygrad.tensor import Tensor

x = Tensor.eye(3, requires_grad=True)
y = Tensor([[2.0,0,-2.0]], requires_grad=True)
z = y.matmul(x).sum()
z.backward()

print(x.grad)  # dz/dx
print(y.grad)  # dz/dy
```

I get

```
<Tensor <LB (3, 3) op:MovementOps.RESHAPE> with grad None>
<Tensor <LB (1, 3) op:MovementOps.RESHAPE> with grad None>
```

I am on a Mac Studio running Ventura (13.0.1 (22A400)) using Python 3.10.8.

Am I missing some kind of low level driver or accelerator or something?
I am new to all of this (my first attempt to look at Deep Learning technology) so I don't understand what I am looking at.  I see references to MovementOps in `accel/opencl/ops_opencl.py` so I'm thinking some kind of post processing step is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the **repr**() function in the Tensor class. Geohot has choosen numpy as backend for tinygrad so calling x.grad.numpy() will give you the result you want.